# Why is my background generator only changing a strip rather than the whole background?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I am trying to create a random background changer in JavaScript but running into issues. First of all, it's only changing a strip of the background rather than the whole page. Another question I have is how do I make the button clickable multiple times to keep randomising the background? The code only lets me click once then needing to refresh to change it again.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

let randomR = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255))
let randomG = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255))
let randomB = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255))

function backColor() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + randomR + ',' + randomG + ',' + randomB + ')';
}

btn.addEventListener('click', backColor)
```

```css
* {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3% auto;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #F07DEA;
}

button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 2px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #000;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button class="btn-class" id="btn" onclick="backColor()">
    Click Me!
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: One question per post, please. See [ask].

Comment: Your body element isn't full height. This would be apparent if you hadn't applied a background color to _every element in the page_.

Answer (score 0):

You want to re-calculate the random R, G, and B values on each click. That means those variables should be defined within the `backColor` function, so they will be recalculated on each invocation of the function instead of only being calculated once per page load.

Comment: thanks everyone, i moved the properties in the * element on css into the body then moved the rgb variables into the function. it works beautifully now. Thank you wise stackoverflow frens